# Extract all characters between _ and .csv

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the date from a series of files of the form:

`costs_per_day_100516.csv`

I have gotten to the point of extracting the `6`, but I don't understand why I can't extract more. What is wrong with the following:

```
test_string = 'search_adwords_cost_by_state_100516.csv'
m = re.search("_([^_])*\.csv", test_string)
m.group(1)
```

This yields `6` rather than `100516`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you just extract the number?

Comment: Put the * inside the brackets: `_([^_]*)\.csv`

Comment: `s.rsplit(".",1)[0].rsplit("_", 1)[1]`

Comment: why didn't you just do `re.search("(\d*)\.csv", test_string).group(1)`? This also extracts the number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = re.search("_([^_]*)\.csv", test_string)
```

The repetition qualifier has to be inside the capture

Answer (score 1):

```
Data_Frame_Name.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), Data_Frame_Name['Column_Name']))
```

This will extract just digits. This may not be applicable for your case but would work well for extracting digits from multiple rows in a column.